# Blazored Modal - does not work on first load, but works after page refresh

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazored

I am trying to consume blazored Modal in my WASM project.  When the page loads, the popup (modal) box does not show up - I get the below error in web console view; however when I refresh the same page (f5), the modal works with no issues.

[image]

Code for Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>rowowasm</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="rowowasm.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazored.Modal/blazored-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
</head>



<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazored.Modal/blazored.modal.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Code for the razor page:

```
@using rowowasm.Shared.Dtos.Clients;

@page "/clientslistpage"

<PageTitle>Edit Clients List</PageTitle>

<div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientsListForEdit OnSelectedItemIDChanged=@FunOnSelectedItemIDChanged @ref="clientslistui" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="col me-5">
            @*<rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientEditWindow @bind-ClientIDForEdit="selectedclientid" OnClientDtoSaved=@(()=>clientslistui.RefreshList())/>*@
            @*<rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientEditWindow @bind-ClientDto="ClientDto" @bind-ClientIDForEdit="selectedclientid" />*@
        </div>

    </div>
</div>



@code{

    //public rowowasm.Shared.Dtos.Clients.ClientDto ClientDto { get; set; } = new ClientDto();

    private int selectedclientid { get; set; }

    protected rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientsListForEdit clientslistui;

    public void FunOnSelectedItemIDChanged(int newclientid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected Item" + newclientid);
        selectedclientid = newclientid;
        ShowEditMovie(newclientid);

    }

    [CascadingParameter] public IModalService Modal { get; set; }

    //checked this https://github.com/Blazored/Modal/blob/main/samples/BlazorWebAssembly/Shared/MessageForm.razor

    void ShowEditMovie(int _clientid)
    {
        var parameters = new ModalParameters();
        parameters.Add(nameof(rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientEditWindow.ClientIDForEdit), _clientid);        

        Modal.Show<rowowasm.UIComponents.UIBase.Clients.ClientEditWindow >("The title", parameters);
    }

}
```

Program.cs code:

```
global using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
global using Blazored.LocalStorage;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using rowowasm.Client;
using Blazored.Modal;


var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();


//builder.Services.AddSingleton<UrlsList, UrlsList>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<rowowasm.UIComponents.Misc.UrlsList, rowowasm.UIComponents.Misc.UrlsList>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredModal();


await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Could you please help me know what error I am doing.

Comment: Why is your script tag outside the html? Browsers are pretty forgiving, but why on earth would you do that?

Comment: @MisterMagoo -  Thanks, now I placed it in head section of index page. Edited the comment.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Posted the razor page now.  Thank you.